# Outlook error when opening .msg: We can' open file [file name] It's possible the file is already open

Tags: microsoft-outlook

When I attempt to open a .msg file in outlook I receive an error that it can't open file.

[image]

The file was originally stored on a network share by another user.

I logged into computer management for that share and confirmed it's not open

I copied the file to my local drive and cannot open it.

I ran outlook in safemode and cannot open it (outlook 2007 and 2013)

I renamed the file to .html and it opens fine in internet explorer.

I renamed the file to .eml and can open it in outlook but without the html formatting.

What is causing this?

Answer (score 0):

A colleague of mine has this issue and I re-saved as HTML to get around the issue as it seemed to happen with any saved msg place on a shared drive. Saving as HTML removed all issues.

I tried an office repair but it didn't rectify.

I have a feeling this is update related.

Comment: I did rename it to html and I can then open it but of course it is then launched in internet explorer, or opened in outlook as the body content.  The user kind of misled me in that they said it was happening to multiple files but it turns out it has only happened once.  I am now thinking something is corrupt with the file...